# Get "Brand" and "Type" from Megento using SQL query

Tags: sql, magento

I have products in magento with "Type" and "Brand" like this

[image]

I have never worked with Magento. I have tried to search over Google but that did not help.

I want to write query to get "Brand" and "Type" of a certain product.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code but before that you need to know what is the attribute code of Brand and Type. and you need to relate that code with this code.

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getIdBySku('your sku');
$Type = $_product->getAttributeText('[Type_attribute_code]');
$Brand = $_product->getAttributeText('[Brand_attribute_code]');
```

> You need to replace entityid with your product id you will get all attribute value.

```
SET @entityid = 203;

SELECT ea.attribute_code, eav.value AS 'value', 'varchar' AS 'type'
FROM catalog_product_entity e
JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar eav
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
WHERE e.entity_id = @entityid
UNION
SELECT ea.attribute_code, eav.value AS 'value', 'int' AS 'type'
FROM catalog_product_entity e
JOIN catalog_product_entity_int eav
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
WHERE e.entity_id = @entityid
UNION
SELECT ea.attribute_code, eav.value AS 'value', 'decimal' AS 'type'
FROM catalog_product_entity e
JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal eav
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
WHERE e.entity_id = @entityid
UNION
SELECT ea.attribute_code, eav.value AS 'value', 'datetime' AS 'type'
FROM catalog_product_entity e
JOIN catalog_product_entity_datetime eav
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
WHERE e.entity_id = @entityid
UNION
SELECT ea.attribute_code, eav.value AS 'value', 'text' AS 'type'
FROM catalog_product_entity e
JOIN catalog_product_entity_text eav
  ON e.entity_id = eav.entity_id
JOIN eav_attribute ea
  ON eav.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
WHERE e.entity_id = @entityid
```

Comment: I dont want PHP code since I am not initiating Magento ... I need RAW SQL query

Comment: I think this is your helpful link [http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/magento-ecommerce/magento-direct-sql-query-get-attribute-values](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/magento-ecommerce/magento-direct-sql-query-get-attribute-values)

Comment: that returns empty results

Answer (score 1):

something along the lines of this should work:

```
SELECT cpe.entity_id, cpe.sku, cpev.value, eaov.value, ea.attribute_code 
FROM magento.catalog_product_entity cpe 
inner join magento.catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev on cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id 
inner join magento.eav_attribute ea on ea.attribute_id = cpev.attribute_id 
inner join magento.eav_attribute_option_value eaov on eaov.option_id = cpev.value
where ea.frontend_label regexp  'Type|Brand';
```

you may need to change the database name (mine here is magento) to match your setup.

Comment: it gave me some un-expected results

Comment: if you give me an example i can help

Comment: I have answered my own question ... you can see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    eav_attribute_option_value.option_id,
    eav_attribute_option_value.`value`,
    catalog_product_index_eav_idx.attribute_id,
    catalog_product_index_eav_idx.entity_id
FROM
    eav_attribute_option_value
INNER JOIN catalog_product_index_eav_idx ON catalog_product_index_eav_idx.`value` = eav_attribute_option_value.option_id
AND catalog_product_index_eav_idx.entity_id = 3566
GROUP BY
    eav_attribute_option_value.option_id
```

This is the query that can fetch Attributes of certain product with ID by specifying `entity_id = 3566`